# Openshift codeigniter error 404 using php7-pfm catridge

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, openshift, codeigniter-3

I have made an Codeigniter application that on my computer I run it via apache and php7.0. But on Openshift I use the `Nginx and PHP 7` cattridge.

When I perform login by doing an http post `index.php/user/login` anything gets redirected as it should while on my computer. But when I perform the very same action on openshift I get error 404.

My application is served on `http://productable-pcmagas.rhcloud.com/` do you have any idea why that happens?

## Edit 1

As requested project Tree:

```
/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/productables2
├── config
│   ├── nginx.d
│   │   ├── default.conf.erb
│   │   └── export_env.erb
│   └── php.d
│       └── extensions.ini
├── license.txt
├── readme.md
└── www
    ├── application
    │   ├── cache
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   ├── config
    │   │   ├── autoload.php
    │   │   ├── config.php
    │   │   ├── constants.php
    │   │   ├── database.php
    │   │   ├── doctypes.php
    │   │   ├── foreign_chars.php
    │   │   ├── hooks.php
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   ├── memcached.php
    │   │   ├── migration.php
    │   │   ├── mimes.php
    │   │   ├── profiler.php
    │   │   ├── routes.php
    │   │   ├── smileys.php
    │   │   └── user_agents.php
    │   ├── controllers
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   ├── Migrate.php
    │   │   ├── Panel.php
    │   │   └── User.php
    │   ├── core
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   ├── helpers
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   └── valuecheck_helper.php
    │   ├── hooks
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── language
    │   │   ├── english
    │   │   │   └── index.html
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   ├── libraries
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   ├── logs
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 001_CreateUserTable.php
    │   │   └── 002_CreateProductsTable.php
    │   ├── models
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   ├── ModProducts.php
    │   │   └── ModUser.php
    │   ├── third_party
    │   │   ├── EmptyParamException.php
    │   │   ├── index.html
    │   │   ├── LoginException.php
    │   │   └── WrongTypeParamException.php
    │   └── views
    │       ├── ajax_403_view.php
    │       ├── errors
    │       │   ├── cli
    │       │   │   ├── error_404.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_db.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_exception.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_general.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_php.php
    │       │   │   └── index.html
    │       │   ├── html
    │       │   │   ├── error_404.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_db.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_exception.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_general.php
    │       │   │   ├── error_php.php
    │       │   │   └── index.html
    │       │   └── index.html
    │       ├── footer.php
    │       ├── header.php
    │       ├── index.html
    │       ├── javascript_view.php
    │       ├── json_view.php
    │       ├── login.php
    │       └── panel.php
    ├── assets
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── AdminLTE.min.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
    │   │   ├── datatables.min.css
    │   │   └── skin-green.min.css
    │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
    │   └── js
    │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
    │       ├── datatables.js
    │       └── jquery.min.js
    ├── composer.json
    ├── index.php
    └── system
        ├── core
        │   ├── Benchmark.php
        │   ├── CodeIgniter.php
        │   ├── Common.php
        │   ├── compat
        │   │   ├── hash.php
        │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   ├── mbstring.php
        │   │   ├── password.php
        │   │   └── standard.php
        │   ├── Config.php
        │   ├── Controller.php
        │   ├── Exceptions.php
        │   ├── Hooks.php
        │   ├── index.html
        │   ├── Input.php
        │   ├── Lang.php
        │   ├── Loader.php
        │   ├── Log.php
        │   ├── Model.php
        │   ├── Output.php
        │   ├── Router.php
        │   ├── Security.php
        │   ├── URI.php
        │   └── Utf8.php
        ├── database
        │   ├── DB_cache.php
        │   ├── DB_driver.php
        │   ├── DB_forge.php
        │   ├── DB.php
        │   ├── DB_query_builder.php
        │   ├── DB_result.php
        │   ├── DB_utility.php
        │   ├── drivers
        │   │   ├── cubrid
        │   │   │   ├── cubrid_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── cubrid_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── cubrid_result.php
        │   │   │   ├── cubrid_utility.php
        │   │   │   └── index.html
        │   │   ├── ibase
        │   │   │   ├── ibase_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── ibase_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── ibase_result.php
        │   │   │   ├── ibase_utility.php
        │   │   │   └── index.html
        │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   ├── mssql
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── mssql_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── mssql_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── mssql_result.php
        │   │   │   └── mssql_utility.php
        │   │   ├── mysql
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── mysql_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── mysql_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── mysql_result.php
        │   │   │   └── mysql_utility.php
        │   │   ├── mysqli
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── mysqli_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── mysqli_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── mysqli_result.php
        │   │   │   └── mysqli_utility.php
        │   │   ├── oci8
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── oci8_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── oci8_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── oci8_result.php
        │   │   │   └── oci8_utility.php
        │   │   ├── odbc
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── odbc_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── odbc_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── odbc_result.php
        │   │   │   └── odbc_utility.php
        │   │   ├── pdo
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── pdo_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── pdo_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── pdo_result.php
        │   │   │   ├── pdo_utility.php
        │   │   │   └── subdrivers
        │   │   │       ├── index.html
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_4d_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_4d_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_cubrid_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_cubrid_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_dblib_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_dblib_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_firebird_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_firebird_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_ibm_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_ibm_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_informix_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_informix_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_mysql_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_mysql_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_oci_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_oci_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_odbc_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_odbc_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_pgsql_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_pgsql_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_sqlite_driver.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_sqlite_forge.php
        │   │   │       ├── pdo_sqlsrv_driver.php
        │   │   │       └── pdo_sqlsrv_forge.php
        │   │   ├── postgre
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── postgre_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── postgre_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── postgre_result.php
        │   │   │   └── postgre_utility.php
        │   │   ├── sqlite
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── sqlite_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── sqlite_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── sqlite_result.php
        │   │   │   └── sqlite_utility.php
        │   │   ├── sqlite3
        │   │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   │   ├── sqlite3_driver.php
        │   │   │   ├── sqlite3_forge.php
        │   │   │   ├── sqlite3_result.php
        │   │   │   └── sqlite3_utility.php
        │   │   └── sqlsrv
        │   │       ├── index.html
        │   │       ├── sqlsrv_driver.php
        │   │       ├── sqlsrv_forge.php
        │   │       ├── sqlsrv_result.php
        │   │       └── sqlsrv_utility.php
        │   └── index.html
        ├── fonts
        │   ├── index.html
        │   └── texb.ttf
        ├── helpers
        │   ├── array_helper.php
        │   ├── captcha_helper.php
        │   ├── cookie_helper.php
        │   ├── date_helper.php
        │   ├── directory_helper.php
        │   ├── download_helper.php
        │   ├── email_helper.php
        │   ├── file_helper.php
        │   ├── form_helper.php
        │   ├── html_helper.php
        │   ├── index.html
        │   ├── inflector_helper.php
        │   ├── language_helper.php
        │   ├── number_helper.php
        │   ├── path_helper.php
        │   ├── security_helper.php
        │   ├── smiley_helper.php
        │   ├── string_helper.php
        │   ├── text_helper.php
        │   ├── typography_helper.php
        │   ├── url_helper.php
        │   └── xml_helper.php
        ├── index.html
        ├── language
        │   ├── english
        │   │   ├── calendar_lang.php
        │   │   ├── date_lang.php
        │   │   ├── db_lang.php
        │   │   ├── email_lang.php
        │   │   ├── form_validation_lang.php
        │   │   ├── ftp_lang.php
        │   │   ├── imglib_lang.php
        │   │   ├── index.html
        │   │   ├── migration_lang.php
        │   │   ├── number_lang.php
        │   │   ├── pagination_lang.php
        │   │   ├── profiler_lang.php
        │   │   ├── unit_test_lang.php
        │   │   └── upload_lang.php
        │   └── index.html
        └── libraries
            ├── Cache
            │   ├── Cache.php
            │   ├── drivers
            │   │   ├── Cache_apc.php
            │   │   ├── Cache_dummy.php
            │   │   ├── Cache_file.php
            │   │   ├── Cache_memcached.php
            │   │   ├── Cache_redis.php
            │   │   ├── Cache_wincache.php
            │   │   └── index.html
            │   └── index.html
            ├── Calendar.php
            ├── Cart.php
            ├── Driver.php
            ├── Email.php
            ├── Encryption.php
            ├── Encrypt.php
            ├── Form_validation.php
            ├── Ftp.php
            ├── Image_lib.php
            ├── index.html
            ├── Javascript
            │   ├── index.html
            │   └── Jquery.php
            ├── Javascript.php
            ├── Migration.php
            ├── Pagination.php
            ├── Parser.php
            ├── Profiler.php
            ├── Session
            │   ├── drivers
            │   │   ├── index.html
            │   │   ├── Session_database_driver.php
            │   │   ├── Session_files_driver.php
            │   │   ├── Session_memcached_driver.php
            │   │   └── Session_redis_driver.php
            │   ├── index.html
            │   ├── Session_driver.php
            │   ├── SessionHandlerInterface.php
            │   └── Session.php
            ├── Table.php
            ├── Trackback.php
            ├── Typography.php
            ├── Unit_test.php
            ├── Upload.php
            ├── User_agent.php
            ├── Xmlrpc.php
            ├── Xmlrpcs.php
            └── Zip.php
```

## Edit 2

I also have the following settings file:

`default.conf.erb` (nginx config)

```
server {
    root              <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/www;
    listen            <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_PORT'] %>;
    server_name       <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'] %>;
    index             index.php index.html index.htm <%= ENV['NGINX_EXTRA_INDEX'] %>;

    set_real_ip_from  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP'] %>;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

    # avoid caching by proxies
    add_header        Cache-Control private;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_PHP_DIR'] %>/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        include        openshift_params;

        # uncomment to export all environment variables to fastcgi
        #include        <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/config/nginx.d/export_env;
    }

    # avoid unnecessary log
    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Handle any other URI
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

`export_env.erb` (enviromental variables or something like that)

```
<%
ENV.each do |name, value|
    puts "fastcgi_param #{name} '#{value}';" unless name.start_with?("OPENSHIFT_");
end
%>
```

All of them are under `config/nginx.d` folder of the openshift's github repository,

Comment: Are you sure the .php(s) files are located in the correct directory?
The action of the form is `http://productable-pcmagas.rhcloud.com/user/login` which doesn't exist. EDIT : Don't know much about CodeIgniter, but shouldn't it be under /application/views etc.

Comment: Well actualy codeingiter the url should be `http://productable-pcmagas.rhcloud.com/index.php/user/login` and of course it does not map under views.

Comment: Could you edit your question and show the "tree"? (folders/subfolders)